# Meteor Galaxy Autoscaling

Tags: meteor, hosting, meteor-galaxy

Does Meteor Galaxy provide support for auto scaling like Modulus provides?

Example: if more than 60% of CPU or memory consumed than it should auto scale and add another container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not. Currently the best option seems to be [galaxy-autoscale](https://github.com/jehartzog/galaxy-autoscale), which will do it for you effectively by automatically clicking the scale buttons on Galaxy's interface.